# Reduce the time complexity of the code to find duplicates in an Array from N*N

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I was recently asked in an interview to write code to determine if an array of integers contains duplicates simple as it was i confidently told him that i would iterate the elements  and add each one to an new array if the array doesn't contain  the element already if it does i return true else return false  complexity

the code would be like this

```
//complexity is N*N
    public static boolean findIfArrayHasDuplicates(int[] array){


        int[] newArr = new int[array.length];
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int var: array){
            if(intList.contains(var)){
                return true;
            }else{
                intList.add(var);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }   
}
```

He asked me to calculate the time complexity of the code i have written

I answered

N for iteration of the loop
N(N+1)/2 for finding if the element exists in in new list
N for adding the elements in the list

total N +N + N*N/2 + N/2  in O() notation multiplying by 2 and simplifying as N tends to infinity this can be simplified **O(N^2)**

he went on to ask me if there is any better way i answered add the elements to a set and compare the size if the size of set is less than than of the array it contains duplicates , asked what is the complexity of it guess what its still **O(N^2)** because of the code that adds elements to the set will have to first see if its in the set already . 
How can I reduce the complexity from **O(N^2)** using as much as memory needed.
Any ideas how this can be done ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do the same thing with the set as what you're doing wit your array, i.e. stop the loop as soon as you found a duplicate?

Comment: yes that is also an improvement that should be done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> he went on to ask me if there is any better way i answered add the elements to a set and compare the size if the size of set is less than than of the array it contains duplicates , asked what is the complexity of it **guess what its still NN because of the code that adds elements to the set will have to first see if its in the set already**

That's wrong. If you are adding the elements to a `HashSet`, it takes expected `O(1)` time to add each element (which includes checking if the element is already present), since all you have to do is compute the `hashCode` to locate the bin that may contain the element (takes constant time), and then search the elements stored in that bin (which also takes expected constant time, assuming the average number of elements in each bin is bound by a constant).

Therefore the total running time is `O(N)`, and there's nothing to improve (you can't find duplicates in less than `O(N)`).

Comment: how would the set determine if the element already exists in the hash set  without iterating  each time ?

Comment: As explained by the answer: by computing its hashCode, and check if the bucket for that hashCode contains the Integer. Google for "how does a HashSet work" or "how does a HashMap work".

Comment: @Sam2016 You should read about `HashSet` (or hash table in general). You compute the `hashCode()` of the element you wish to add, and that leads you to the location within the Set that may contain that element. You don't have to iterate over all the existing elements.

Comment: Thanks eran Guess i answered it right in the interview but the interviewer insisted its N*N may be he also did not knew how hash set would work :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be useful if you would look at basic working mechanisms of a `HashSet`. A `HashSet` is internally an array, but data accesses, such as "checking if an element exists", or "adding/deleting an element", is of time complexity O(1), because it takes on a *mapping mechanism* to map an object to the index storing it. For example, if you have a HashSet and an integer and you do a `hashSet.contains(integer)`, the program will first take the integer and calculate the hash code of it, and then use the mapping mechanism (differs from implementation to implementation) to find the index storing it. Say we have a hash code of 4, and we map to an index of 4 using the simplest mapping mechanism, then we will check if the 4th element of the underlying array is empty. If it is, `hashSet.contains(integer)` will return `true`, otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of code provided is O(N^2). However, the code given follows is complexity O(N). It uses HashSet, which required O(1) operation to insert and search.

```
    public static boolean findIfArrayHasDuplicates(int[] array){

            HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
            set.add(array[0]);

            for (int index = 1; index < array.length; index++) {
                    if(!set.add(array[index]))
                            return true;
            }

            return false;
     }
```